# Error: invalid_grant when trying to authenticate to google api node

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, jwt

The path to the json file is correct. It is returning a invalid grant error. I don't understand the error if someone could help it would be nice.Thank you.

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var key = require('path to json file');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key,["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"], null);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return;
 }
else{
  console.log("success");
 }

});
```

Comment: Is the time correct on the machine you are using?

Comment: yes I verified it ,the time is correct.

Comment: I fixed it by setting my time behind by 5 minutes